# changing css visibility on click event in backbone

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js

There's a fiddle demonstrating my problem here http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/RRXnK/232/

In my Rails app which uses Backbone, I have some html set up like this

```
<div class="row category">

  <div class="editcategory">edit category</div>  

  <div class="span10 category">blah</div>
</div>
```

The css for .span10.category is by default hidden

```
.span10.category {

    visibility: hidden;
}
```

In a Backbone view, I set the el to

```
 el: '.row.category',
```

so that anything inside it (I assume) is within the scope of the view i.e. it can be manipulated by javascript in the view. I then put a click event on the .editcategory class

```
'click .editcategory': 'editCategory'
```

and tried to make the class that is hidden by default visible once the click event is triggered like so

```
editCategory: function(){
    console.log("edit Category");
     $('.span10 category').css('visiblity', 'visible');

   }
```

However, it's not working (even though the console log is triggered). I also tried to set the selector like this

```
  $('.span10.category')
```

Because the .span10 .category class is within `.row category` div, I'm assuming I can change the css on it, but I'm doing it wrong somehow. I also tried `fadeIn();` instead of the `css` method but no difference.

Can anyone explain how I can change the visibility on the click event. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.span10 category').css('visiblity', 'visible');
```

You spelled `visibility` incorrectly. You forgot the i after the b.

```
$('.span10 category').css('visibility', 'visible');
```